# How to exclude programs from writing to RAM block cache? (e.g. media player)

Tags: cache, ram, block-comment

When playing back huge video files, the media player ravenously consumes disk cache and thus kicks out blocks cached by other programs.

Not to confuse with LinuxAteMyRam.com.

I would like the media player just to read the video files without the contents of the video files to be stored into the block cache inside of the RAM, which could lead to other programs slowing down because the video player kicked out their cached RAM data from the disk cache.

---

Related question: [Deactivating disk cache for specific device or partition?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/476658/deactivating-disk-cache-for-specific-device-or-partition)