# Deactivating disk cache for specific device or partition? (play 2160p video off SD card without sacrificing RAM space other programs need)

Tags: cache, ram, sd-card, data

I would like to deactivate the disk cache for /dev/mmcblk0p1 in order to preserve more RAM for other system parts while playing 2160p video off /dev/mmcblk0p1.

2160p videos ravenously wipe the RAM cache from other programs. After watching 2160p video, **other programs need to access files from the original disk again** because the 2160p video footage occupied the RAM cache.

How can I exclude /dev/mmcblk0p1 selectively from the disk cache?

---

Related question: [How to exclude programs from writing to RAM block cache? (e.g. media player)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466151/how-to-exclude-programs-from-writing-to-ram-block-cache-e-g-media-player).

Comment: How are you reading the video?  O_DIRECT may be the solution: https://serverfault.com/questions/545708/direct-i-o-on-linux or https://superuser.com/questions/242928/disable-linux-read-and-write-file-cache-on-partition

Comment: Great thanks, @Devon. I will now give `mount -o dio` a try.

Comment: There is also -o directio